# Spark Stream kafka stream - returned rdd doesn't do anything in foreachRDD

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am facing a weird issue here, I am reading `Avro` records from kafka and trying to deserialize it and store it into a file. I am able to get the records from Kafka but some how when I try to use a function on the rdd records it refuses to do anything

```
import java.util.UUID
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDecoder
import com.my.project.avro.AvroDeserializer
import com.my.project.util.SparkJobLogging
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Minutes, Seconds, StreamingContext, Time}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._
import kafka.serializer.{DefaultDecoder, StringDecoder}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.{DStream}

object KafkaConsumer extends SparkJobLogging {
  var schemaRegistry: SchemaRegistryClient = null
  val url="url:8181"
  schemaRegistry= new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(url, 1000)

  def createKafkaStream(ssc: StreamingContext): DStream[(String,Array[Byte])] = {
    val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](
      "zookeeper.connect" -> "zk.server:2181",
      "group.id" -> s"${UUID.randomUUID().toString}",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "smallest",
      "bootstrap.servers" -> "bootstrap.server:9092",
      "zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms" -> "6000",
      "schema.registry.url" ->"registry.url:8181"
    )

    val topic = "my.topic"
    KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, Array[Byte], StringDecoder, DefaultDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, Set(topic))
  }

   def processRecord(  avroStream: Array[Byte])={
    println(AvroDeserializer.toRecord(avroStream, schemaRegistry) )
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("AvroDeserilizer")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))
    val topicStream = createKafkaStream(ssc)map(_._2)
    topicStream.foreachRDD(
      rdd => if (!rdd.isEmpty()){
        logger.info(rdd.count())
        rdd.foreach(avroRecords=> processRecord(avroRecords))
      }
    )
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}

object AvroDeserializer extends SparkJobLogging{
  def toRecord(buffer: Array[Byte], registry: SchemaRegistryClient): GenericRecord = {
    val bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer)
    bb.get() // consume MAGIC_BYTE
    val schemaId = bb.getInt // consume schemaId
    val schema = registry.getByID(schemaId) // consult the Schema Registry
    val reader = new GenericDatumReader[GenericRecord](schema)
    val decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(buffer, bb.position(), bb.remaining(), null)
    reader.read(null, decoder) //null -> as we are not providing any datum
  }
}
```

Till statement `logger.info(rdd.count())` everything works fine and I see the exact record counts in the log. However after that nothing works.
When I tired

```
val record= rdd.first()
processRecord(record)
```

it worked but `rdd.foreach(avroRecords=> processRecord(avroRecords))` and `rdd.map(avroRecords=> processRecord(avroRecords))` doesn't works. It just prints below on every streaming call:

```
 17/05/14 01:01:24 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 2 finished: foreach at KafkaConsumer.scala:56, took 42.684999 s
 17/05/14 01:01:24 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1494738000000 ms.0 from job set of time 1494738000000 ms
 17/05/14 01:01:24 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Total delay: 84.888 s for time 1494738000000 ms (execution: 84.719 s)
 17/05/14 01:01:24 INFO scheduler.ReceivedBlockTracker: Deleting batches ArrayBuffer()
 17/05/14 01:01:24 INFO scheduler.InputInfoTracker: remove old batch metadata: 
 17/05/14 01:01:26 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 0 executor containers
 17/05/14 01:01:26 WARN yarn.YarnAllocator: Expected to find pending requests, but found none.
 17/05/14 01:01:29 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 0 executor containers
 17/05/14 01:01:29 WARN yarn.YarnAllocator: Expected to find pending requests, but found none.
```

It just prints the last 2 lines in the log till the next streaming context call.

Comment: How is your is your logger setup? Does it only print to the console? The code inside `rdd.foreach` is executed on the Executors and you don't see its output in the driver.

Comment: I am using `trait SparkJobLogging {
  @transient protected lazy val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass.getName)
}` and I see the logs in cloudera cluster.

Comment: How do you check the logs? What tools do you use? Do you use `yarn logs` or the web UI?

Comment: I use Cloudera Manager Server UI to check the logs. I tried `rdd.foreach(avroRecords=> processRecord(avroRecords)).saceAsTextFile("/data/")` but it doesn't save the data in the `rdd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the above method didn't worked for me but I found a different way in confluent documentation. The `KafkaAvroDecoder` will communicate with schema registry, get the schema and deserialize the data. So it removes the need of custom deserializer.

```
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDecoder

val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> brokers,
  "schema.registry.url" -> schemaRegistry,
  "key.converter.schema.registry.url" -> schemaRegistry,
  "value.converter.schema.registry.url" -> schemaRegistry,
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "smallest")
val topicSet = Set(topics)
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[Object, Object, KafkaAvroDecoder, KafkaAvroDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicSet).map(_._2)
messages.foreachRDD { 
rdd => if (!rdd.isEmpty()){
    logger.info(rdd.count())
    rdd.saveAsTextFile("/data/")
  }
)
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
}
}
```

Dependency jar: `kafka-avro-serializer-3.1.1.jar`. This is working perfectly for me right now and I hope this will helpful to someone in future.

Answer (score 1):

Your `println` statements are being run on distributed workers not in the current process, so you dont see them. You could try replacing `println` with `log.info` verify this.

Ideally you should be turning your `DStream[Array[Byte]]` to a `DStream[GenericRecord]` and write that to a file, use `.saveAsTextFiles` or something. You may want a `stream.take()` in there because the stream could be infinite.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it is really informative. I found another way for my use case which is working however I will still try the solution that you mentioned when I will get time.

Answer (score 1):

```
val topicStream = createKafkaStream(ssc)map(_._2)
topicStream.foreachRDD(
  rdd => if (!rdd.isEmpty()){
    logger.info(rdd.count())
    rdd.foreach(avroRecords=> processRecord(avroRecords))
```

dstream.foreachRDD is a powerful primitive that allows data to be sent out to external systems. However, it is important to understand how to use this primitive correctly and efficiently. Some of the common mistakes to avoid are as follows.

DStreams are executed lazily by the output operations, just like RDDs are lazily executed by RDD actions. Specifically, RDD actions inside the DStream output operations force the processing of the received data. Hence, if your application does not have any output operation, or has output operations like dstream.foreachRDD() without any RDD action inside them, then nothing will get executed. The system will simply receive the data and discard it.

Comment: Thanks Irshad for your answer, you have really provided valueable information. I tried the `rdd.saveAsTestfile` too inside the loop and I think it is a RDD action and it didn't worked. I might be doing something really silly in my code. I found a better solution and its working for now. I will still check the issue with the older approach.